# I accidentally deleted my files in a repository on github, but I still have them locally

Tags: github, git-submodules, delete-file, undo, revert

I accidentally deleted my files in a repository on Github, but I still have them locally.  I'm having trouble pushing them back up because it says that I have a submodule. And the files are showing greyed out.  How can I fix this? [screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRtYB.png) The  double folders are submodules that are not clickable

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of error?

Comment: Just reset the master (?) branch head on github..?

Comment: I've added the screenshot to the original post now.

Comment: I've tried reseting the master branch head on github, all my files previously are in the same directory and  now they are submodules also and I dont want to delete them

Comment: You can add submodules with command: `git submodule add {url} {submodule}`.
Also, can you create a new repo? on your local repo enter: `git remote rm {url}` then `git remote add {new_repo_url}`. Or delete `.git` directory and initialize git again and add your repo to it.

Comment: I'm actually trying to merge the submodule with the master branch, because the submodule doesn't show like the master branch does.